# Groups in a category

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Steve Awodey defines a group in a category as a diagram ([group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCHtj.png)) satisfying the conditions that the following diagrams commute: [first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSvLM.png), [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLN19.png), [third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPfa6.png).
But then he says:

> Note that the requirement that these diagrams commute is equivalent to the
>   more familiar condition that, for all (generalized) elements, $x,y,z: Z  \rightarrow{} G$ the following equations hold:$m(m(x, y), z) = m(x,m(y, z))\\ 
> m(x, u) = x = m(u, x)\\
> m(x, ix) = u = m(ix, x)$

How do these equations follow from the definition of a group? Do i understand correctly that $m(x,y)$ stands for $m \circ \left \langle x,y \right \rangle$? And if it is, how to derive from $m \circ (m\times 1) = m \circ (1 \times m) \circ  \cong$ (that corresponds to the first diagram)  this equation: $m \circ \left \langle m \circ\left \langle x,y \right \rangle,z \right \rangle = m \circ \left \langle x,m\circ\left \langle y,z \right \rangle \right \rangle$ for all (generalized) elements $x,y,z:Z\rightarrow G$

Comment: There is a discussion of group objects in other categories in *Algebra: Chapter 0* that you may want to glance at.

Comment: $m\  \textit{is}$ a function. Its domain is a subset of Cartesian product of the $sets$ Hom$(Z,G)$ and range, a subset of Hom$(Z,G)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pre-compose both sides of $m\circ(m\times id_G)=m\circ(id_G\times m)\circ\alpha$ with $\langle\langle x,y\rangle, z\rangle$, $\alpha$ being the associator, and start computing. (You didn't ask for it, but for the other direction just pick $Z=G$ and $x$, $y$, and $z$ as as the appropriate projections, specifically $\pi_1\circ\pi_1$, $\pi_2\circ\pi_1$, and $\pi_2$ respectively.)

Comment: Assuming that $m(x,y) := m \circ \left \langle x,y \right \rangle $ is correct, I've proved this equality using UMP of product several times. But Awodey doesn't state that $m(x,y) := m \circ \left \langle x,y \right \rangle $ and this wasn't evident to me. So it was confusing.

Comment: One way to conceptualize generalized elements is to view them as the presheaves produced by the Yoneda embedding where "presheaf" is just a fancy way of saying a functor $\mathcal C^{op}\to\mathbf{Set}$. An arrow $f:X\to Y$ in $\mathcal C$ becomes a natural transformation $f\circ - :\mathsf{Hom}(-,X)\to\mathsf{Hom}(-,Y)$ which is just a family of normal set-theoretic functions in this case. If we write $\bar f$ for this natural transformation, then we get $\bar f(x)$ (which means $f\circ x$) for $x\in\mathsf{Hom}(-,X)$. (cont'd.)

Comment: ... Since $\mathsf{Hom}(-,A\times B)\cong\mathsf{Hom}(-,A)\times\mathsf{Hom}(-,B)$ this works for multi-argument functions. In fact, *all* limits and colimits exist and are computed pointwise for presheaves so these constructions  are basically the same as for sets. (Further, the category of presheaves is a topos which enables even more set-theoretic reasoning.) This is one perspective on why generalized elements are helpful. They correspond to embedding our category, $\mathcal C$, into a category that behaves very much like $\mathbf{Set}$ which enables us to reason like we're used to.

Comment: Could you clarify, while proving in the other direction, how to get from this equality: $m\circ(m\times id_{G})\circ\left \langle \left \langle id_{G},id_{G} \right \rangle,id_{G} \right \rangle = m \circ (id_{G} \times m) \circ \alpha \: \circ \left \langle id_{G},\left \langle id_{G},id_{G} \right \rangle \right \rangle $ the desired result: $m\circ(m\times id_{G}) = m \circ (id_{G} \times m) \circ \alpha$

Comment: First, you shouldn't be associating the right-most arrow differently. They're supposed to be the same arrow, the associator $\alpha$ handles reassociating. Also, you aren't talking about the equation I was referring to. That said, I did say the wrong thing, and I should have said insert the appropriate projections.

Comment: That was just a typo. Of course, the correct equality $m\circ(m\times id_{G})\circ\left \langle \left \langle id_{G},id_{G} \right \rangle,id_{G} \right \rangle = m \circ (id_{G} \times m) \circ \alpha \: \circ \left \langle \left \langle id_{G},id_{G} \right \rangle,id_{G} \right \rangle$. Now everything is clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One has to realise that  $m:(x,y)\to m(x,y)$ is the multiplication of the group, $u$ the identity and $ix$ the inverse of $x$ and we have the more familiar definition of a group.

So we have just rewritten in arrows associativity, the definition of identity and the definition of an inverse element

Comment: The first diagram starts with the canonical isomorphism $G\times (G\times G)\to (G\times G)\times G$. Basically it says that $(x,(y,z))\to ((x,y),z$ is an isomorphism, just a consequence of the definition of product. Then commutativity of the diagram tells us that $m\circ (1\circ m)=m\circ (m\circ 1)$